# Couldn't add current user after signing up without reloading (Next JS + Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am using the Auth Provider to manage my Firebase auth information. I want to be able to use `currentUser` as soon as I sign up, but it won't set without reloading.

I tried to `setCurrentUser` out of the Auth Provider and set it, but I could not get it to work either.

*contexts/Auth.tsx*

```
const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>(null!)

export const AuthProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: ReactNode
})  => {
  const [currentFBUser, setCurrentFBUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null)
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<any>(null)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const { update } = useIntercom()

  /**
   * SUBSCRIBE user auth state from firebase
   */
   useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {

      if (!user) {
        setCurrentFBUser(null)
        setIsLoading(false)
        return
      }
      await setCurrentFBUser(user)

      const storeUser = await userRepository.findById(user.uid)
      if (!storeUser) {
        setCurrentUser(null)
        setIsLoading(false)
        return
      }

      await setCurrentUser(storeUser)

      /* UPDATE Intercom props */
      if(currentUser) {
        update({
          name: currentUser.name,
          email: currentUser.email
        })
      }

      setIsLoading(false)
      return () => {
        unsubscribe()
      }
    })

    }, [])

    const logout = useCallback(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();

      signOut(auth).then(() => {
        window.location.reload()
      }).catch((err) => {
        toast.error(err.message)
      });
    }, [])

    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{
        currentFBUser,
        currentUser,
        setCurrentUser,
        isLoading,
        logout,
      }}>
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useAuthContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext)
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within the AuthProvider')
  }
  return context
}
```

*signup.tsx*

```
...
  const { currentFBUser, isLoading, setCurrentUser } = useAuthContext()

  const signup = handleSubmit(
    async (data) => {
      if (data.password != data.confirmPassword) {
        toast.error('Your password is not matched!')
        return
      }

      const auth = getAuth()
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data.email, data.password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const auth = userCredential.user
        if (!auth) return

        const { email, uid } = auth
        if (!email) return

        const user = userRepository.findOrCreate(email, uid)
        setCurrentUser(user)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error(err.message)
      });
    },
    (err: any) => {
      toast.error(err.message)
    },
  )
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call again getAuth() instead of using the response from createUserWithEmailAndPassword

```
const { currentFBUser, isLoading, setCurrentUser } = useAuthContext()

  const signup = handleSubmit(
    async (data) => {
      if (data.password != data.confirmPassword) {
        toast.error('Your password is not matched!')
        return
      }

      const auth = getAuth()
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data.email, data.password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
       // const auth = userCredential.user
    const auth = getAuth().currentUser
        if (!auth) return

        const { email, uid } = auth
        if (!email) return

        const user = userRepository.findOrCreate(email, uid)
        setCurrentUser(user)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error(err.message)
      });
    },
    (err: any) => {
      toast.error(err.message)
    },
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But it couldn't work...